# Getting first element and returning after apply a function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am new in Java 8, I want to make a method that gets the first element that matched and returning after apply a function

```
public void test() {
    List<String> features = Arrays.asList("Lambdas", "Default Method", "Stream API", "Date and Time API");

    String str = features
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> "Lambdas".equals(s))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(this::toLowerCase);
}

private String toLowerCase (String str) {
    return str.toLowerCase();
}
```

but I got an Incompatible types error.

Comment: Don't use `ifPresent`. It's void. Use `map` followed by `get`, `orElse`, `orElseGet`, ...

Comment: Nice list of features :-)

Comment: As an aside my taste would be for `s -> s.equals("Lambdas")`. If you insist on the [yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), you may also use a method reference: `"Lambdas"::equals`.

Comment: Do you explicitly want to use `Stream API` for this purpose? It can also be achieved by leveraging `features.contains()` method. And if this condition evaluates to `true` then simply return the lowercased value of the `"Lambdas"` String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional.ifPresent` accepts a `Consumer`, and doesn't return any value. Use `map`:

```
String str =
    features.stream()
            .filter(s -> "Lambdas".equals(s))
            .findFirst()
            .map(this::toLowerCase)
            .orElse(null); // default value or orElseThrow
```

Or, as Holger suggested, you can move the `map` step into the stream pipeline:

```
String str =
    features.stream()
            .filter(s -> "Lambdas".equals(s))
            .map(this::toLowerCase)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null); // default value or orElseThrow
```

Comment: …and using `map` in the stream chain, i.e. `.filter(s -> "Lambdas".equals(s)) .map(this::toLowerCase) .findFirst() …` would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
 String str =
        features
            .stream()
            .filter("Lambdas"::equals)
            .findFirst()
            .map(this::toLowerCase)
            .orElse("AnythingElse");
```

`findFirst` returns an `Optional`, as such use some method on that `Optional`, like `orElse` that would *return* some String instance.

Look closely at what `Optional::ifPresent` takes as input - it's a `Consumer`, thus read it as "take that String as input, do something with it and return nothing".

Answer (score 2):

You can map the string if found `orElse` assign `null` to it:

```
List<String> features = Arrays.asList("Lambdas", "Default Method", "Stream API", "Date and Time API");
String str = features
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> "Lambdas".equals(s))
        .findFirst()
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .orElse(null);
```